# Encode to Unicode UTF-8 not working

Tags: node.js, unicode, utf-8

My Code -

```
var utf8 = require('utf8');
var  y = utf8.encode('एस एम एस गपशप');
console.log(y);
```

Input -
`एस एम एस गपशप`

Expecting Output -  `\xE0\xA4\x8F\xE0\xA4\xB8\x20\xE0\xA4\x8F\xE0\xA4\xAE\x20\xE0\xA4\x8F\xE0\xA4\xB8\x20\xE0\xA4\x97\xE0\xA4\xAA\xE0\xA4\xB6\xE0\xA4\xAA`

[Example Encoding using utf8.js](https://mothereff.in/utf-8#%E0%A4%8F%E0%A4%B8%20%E0%A4%8F%E0%A4%AE%20%E0%A4%8F%E0%A4%B8%20%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%AA)

Output -

```
à¤à¤¸ à¤à¤® à¤à¤¸ à¤à¤ªà¤¶à¤ª
```

**What am I doing wrong? Please help!**

Comment: FWIW, `\x..` is ***not "UTF-8"***. For what purpose are you trying to encoding this string?

Comment: @deceze Could you please tell me what is this encoding as shown in the example.

Comment: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=3584&number=128&utf8=string-literal

Comment: `\x..` is the *hex escape notation* for a string containing bytes representing characters in the UTF-8 charset. "एस एम एस गपशप" encoded in UTF-8 should preferably actually display as "एस एम एस गपशप" on your screen.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for clarifying that. How do i achieve hex escape notation for the string?

Answer (score 1):

That code appears to be working. That output looks like UTF-8 bytes interpreted as some 8-bit character set, most likely ISO-8859-1, which is easily recognisable by the repeating patterns.

That example output is just how you would represent that string in source code.

Try this:

```
var utf8 = require('utf8');
var  y = utf8.encode('एस');
console.log(y);
console.log('\xE0\xA4\x8F\xE0\xA4\xB8');
```

You will probably see the same output twice.

You can easily write some code to get that hexadecimal forms back using a lookup table and the `charCodeAt` function, but it is a rather unusual way to represent a string in JavaScript. JSON for example either just uses the literal characters, or '\uXXXX' escapes.